# My Google action is deployed but still it shows test version when using it in google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

My google action is deployed and is usable. But when I am using,  it shows test version. 
And also, reviews of users are also not saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch which version you're using for your account by going to the simulator and selecting the "Change version" control and selecting one of the non-test versions.

[image]